# chmod issue with particular user

Tags: php, linux, chmod

I'm starting with chmod. I've set up a group and gave them permission (777) and every user inside the group is able to do whatever they want inside the directory /www/.

However, I need to change the permissions to anyone else. So I wrote down:

```
$ chmod -R o-rwx /www/ && chmod -R o+rw /www/some_interesting_dir
```

Because I wanted only to allow him access to that directory. But he's unable to perform "cd /www/some_interesting_dir", console says permission denied.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `o+rw` you should use `o+rwX` which will apply the execute permission bit to all directories in the structure too, allowing users to actually access them.  (The execute bit is required to `cd` into or read files from a directory or any subdirectory.)

Comment: +1 I was actually unaware of the `+X` for recursively specifying directory permissions.

Comment: @meagar: Thanks. `+X` is actually defined in `man chmod` as "execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user."  So it may alter the permissions of files too if they are e.g. 700.

Answer (score 0):

With directories, the executable bit allows you to view the contents of the directory. You need to add 'o+x' for directories:

```
find -type d -exec chmod o+x "{}" \;
```

Giving other users `+rw` permission seems to defeat the purpose; you're giving everybody write permissions to everything in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

A user must have execute access to the directory he's passing through, the result is that while he can see what's in /www/ he still can't do anything to any of the files in there (As they have their own permissions)

Just `chmod o+x www`

Comment: The guide didn't say so, but it worked! Thank you very much for your fast response!

Comment: We need a way to PM new users to inform them they forgot to mark answered :) Just a general statement...